# Android azure mobile services __includeDeleted in pull?

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-sdk-.net

Is there a built-in way to request the Deleted entities on Pull in the Android and iOS version of Azure Mobile Services?

In the Rest API its clear that you must specify the parameter __includeDeleted=true in order for them to be returned.

Edit: 
After hours of debugging we found out that iOS SDK and propably Android's SDK sends on the URI the

__includeDeleted=1

instead of

__includeDeleted=true

With a simple request from postman its obvious that the first on is not working!

Anyone has a workaround here?

Comment: Hmm, you are correct that the servers are not accepting 1. You could try a fix via the handler/filter logic to do a replace 'includeDeleted=1' to =true on all outbound http requests.  Kinda messy.  Let me see what a real fix would entail.

Comment: We actually solved the problem here by hardcoding on the server the includeDeleted to true. This way we send out the deleted stuff always. Our clients request only for the newer updates, by passing a predicate based on version. 
However, it should be fixed, it took some hours to find this out and maybe in some application our solution will not be possible.

Comment: Ok, a fix is committed for iOS, and a new SDK will be available in the next day or two (or can be built manually from GitHub)  For Android, the SDK doesn't yet know how to handle deleted records, but the dev work is complete.  A new version 2.0.2 for it should also be available soon)

Comment: Do you know if there is Android's SDK source code on GitHub or somewhere ?

Comment: The beta code is in: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/android

Answer (score 1):

We have a beta2 SDK of iOS mobile services SDK that fixes the bug with requesting deleted items: http://aka.ms/gc6fex.

We've also updated our tutorials to work with the new incremental sync functionality in the beta2 SDK: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data/

For Android, you should get the source from GitHub as mentioned in the comments: http://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/android